# C++11 inserting element into a list of arrays

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, stl

I am trying to use an STL container to hold arrays, but I do not know how can I insert elements into it. I was trying different approaches and non of it worked for me. Also google is helpless in this case. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
std::forward_list<int[5]> buffers;
buffers.push_front(); // What should I pass to create uninitialized array
```

Even this approach does not works

```
typedef int Buffer[5];
std::forward_list<Buffer> buffers;
Buffer buff;
buffers.push_front(buff);
```

The only way which works is to wrap array with a class. Then everything is ok, however I wanted to know how should I do this correctly in C++

Comment: You can use built-in array wrapper class `using Buffer = ::std::array<int, 5>; ::std::forward_list<Buffer> buffers; buffers.emplace_front();`

Comment: @VTT, ...just curious @ your comment, is there any valid reason why you are pre-qualifying `std` namespace qualifier with global scope?

Comment: @WhiZTiM It is protection from unexpected name clashes.

Comment: While, that's true. Its way better and cheaper to ban the re-purposing (even temporarily) of `std` for any other identifier, than to be prepending `::std::` everywhere in fear of someone doing that....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cant store pure arrays into STL container

Try this

```
using Buffer = std::vector<int[5]>;
std::forward_list<Buffer> buffers;
buffers.push_front(Buffer());
```

or

```
using Buffer = std::array<int, 5>;
std::forward_list<Buffer> buffers;
buffers.push_front(Buffer());
```

or via pointer to arrays

```
std::forward_list<int*> buffers;
int *ptr = new int[5]{1,2,3,4,5};
buffers.push_front(ptr);

for (int * it : buffers)
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        std::cout << it[i] << std::endl;
```

Comment: If I use std::vector or std::array it will perform two memory allocations on every insertion.  I wanted to use static array to reduce operations on heap.

Comment: @noonespecial You cant store pure arrays to STL, but you can store pointers to them. [Here is the example](https://ideone.com/mXScXi). But i should warn you its very error-prone.